# How run frames without delay in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have built a Flutter animation using 390 frames. These 390 frames run without any errors but always display a white background, flashing-like. I think it has a delay when moving to the next frame.

**sample video**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yEDg4efg1TLu4mW-vUvA3PHA4I4ddoNf/view?usp=sharing

you can see delay how to solve this ?

**code**

```
class _AnimationSpriteAnimationScreenState extends State<AnimationSpriteAnimationScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<int> _animation;
  final List<Image> _spriteImages = [];

  late Image _headImage;

  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  bool isPlaying = false;
  TextEditingController url = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);

    //add sprite images to list
    for (int i = 1; i <= 390; i++) {
      _spriteImages.add(_buildSpriteImage(i));
    }

    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 39),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animation =
        IntTween(begin: 0, end: _spriteImages.length - 1).animate(_controller);

    _controller.repeat();
    _controller.stop();

    //initialize head/face image
    _headImage = Image.network(url.text);

  

    //show snackbar
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _showStartDancingSnackbar();
    });
  }



 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
          return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
            //set sprite width and height according to screen size
            final double spriteWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
            final double spriteHeight = constraints.maxHeight;

            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                //play or pause animation
                if (_controller.isAnimating) {
                  _controller.stop();
                  setState(() {
                    isPlaying = true;
                    audioPlayer.pause();
                  });
                } else {
                  _controller.repeat();
                  setState(() {
                    isPlaying = false;
                    audioPlayer.resume();
                  });
                }

                //play or pause audio
              },
              child: Center(
                child: AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _animation,
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Positioned.fill(
                          child: Center(
                            child: SizedBox(
                                height: spriteHeight,
                                width: spriteWidth,
                                child: _spriteImages[_animation.value]),
                          ),
                        ),
                     
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          });
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  //function to build sprite images
  Image _buildSpriteImage(int index) {
    final AssetImage childImage =
    AssetImage('assets/images/animationframes/ezgif-frame-$index.jpg');
    final Image child = Image(image: childImage, fit: BoxFit.fill);

    return child;
  }

  //function to show snackbar
  void _showStartDancingSnackbar() {
    final snackBar = const SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        'Tap to start dancing',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you are showing 10 frames per second?

Comment: yeah.. It's high or lack ?

Comment: I would say a bit to lacky. For a good quality you should have at least 24 fps. Everything below is noticeable for the human eye.

And it's a very unorthodox way to make a video sequence. May I ask why you do it this way and not for example with a video editing program and use a videoplayer in flutter?

Comment: For my assessment, I have to build this. Actually, you're correct. I can use a videoplayer, but Flutter animation is compulsory.

Comment: Is there a tool, software, or AI tool to create frames? For example, if I upload two frames, such as sitting and standing frames, will the tool generate frames in between the sitting and standing positions?

Comment: Yes. I used one to make youtube videos. I forgot what the name was and also it was not completely free. Using the free version had the thing that a watermark of the publisher was shown in each frame.

Comment: Sorry for being late. Seriously, if you get reminded, could you please mention it? And thank you so much for your support

Comment: @DasunDola, I tried your code. The solution pointed by @ChoiKari works. ```final Image child = Image(image: childImage, fit: BoxFit.fill,gaplessPlayback: true,);``` 
[gaplessPlayback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/gaplessPlayback.html) with the value false is the cause of your issue.
Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you again, bro. It worked when I added your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the "gaplessPlayback" parameter to true in the Image.

```dart
Image(
  image: ...,
  gaplessPlayback: true,
);
```

Comment: thank you for your support. not suited for my code bro

Comment: @DasunDola, I tried your code. The above solution pointed by @ChoiKari works.
```final Image child = Image(image: childImage, fit: BoxFit.fill,gaplessPlayback: true,);```

Comment: heyyy bro that's worked.. 
First of all, I need to apologize for my delay, I was so busy in the last few days.... And thank you so much to both of you for your big support. @Mearaj  , ChoiKarl .Now the animation is working perfectly without any issues.

Comment: @Mearaj You are correct. Choi's code was correct. I added it in the wrong place, that's my bad

Comment: @DasunDola, no worries at all. Thanks to you too :)